# Facets: Show more and Show less functionality

Tags: search

I am interested in a "Show more" and "Show less" functionality in facets like on this page http://ethicshare.org/publications/ethics?sc=publications
How can I do that?I am using search api.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer:You can select the visible items of the facet on the facet display.
E.g. you can select 3 items to be visible.If the facets items are more than 3,by default will appear a Show more/Show less functionality for the facet.
Hope this is clear.
thanks